# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints - LayoutConstraints

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have created a button ( `myTestButton` ) in codebehind in `TestViewController.swift` file as you see in the source code that I have shared bottom of the post. I am getting below error after i rotate the Iphone(scope 2). Why am I getting this error? How can I fix this problem?

**The error in output window in xcode:**

```
device has rotated! is landscape mode?: true
scope: 2
2019-07-14 15:23:14.411875+0300 myproject[12522:4008763] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28029b8e0 UIButton:0x103215110.centerY == UIView:0x103204e10.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28028c550 UIButton:0x103215110.centerY == UIView:0x103204e10.centerY + 60   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28028c550 UIButton:0x103215110.centerY == UIView:0x103204e10.centerY + 60   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-07-14 15:23:14.413028+0300 myproject[12522:4008763] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28029ba70 UIButton:0x103215110.width == UIView:0x103204e10.width - 20   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28028c9b0 UIButton:0x103215110.width == UIView:0x103204e10.width - 40   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28029ba70 UIButton:0x103215110.width == UIView:0x103204e10.width - 20   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

**Here is the source code:**

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

var isOrientationStatusLandscape : Bool = false

let myTestButton : UIButton =
{
    let mytestbutton = UIButton()
    mytestbutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    mytestbutton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return mytestbutton
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupView()
}

override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if self.isOrientationStatusLandscape == true {self.isOrientationStatusLandscape = false} else {self.isOrientationStatusLandscape = true}
    print("device has rotated! is landscape mode?: \(self.isOrientationStatusLandscape)")
    self.setupView()
}

func setupView()
{
    self.prepareTheButton()
}

func prepareTheButton()
{
    view.addSubview(myTestButton)
    if isOrientationStatusLandscape == false
    {
        print("scope: 1")
        myTestButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        myTestButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        myTestButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        myTestButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    }
    else
    {
        print("scope: 2")
        myTestButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
        myTestButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        myTestButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
        myTestButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Because when we rotate you add new constraints without removing the ones you already added. If you rotate 10 times you will have 40 constraints on that poor little button.

Comment: Understood. Dear @matt Can you write me the code to remove existing constrains please? And then i can sign it as a reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 2 arrays

```
 let firstCons = [
     myTestButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor), 
     myTestButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -20),
 ] 

 let secondCons = [
    myTestButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 60), 
    myTestButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -40), 
 ]
```

Then play with `activate`/`deactivate`

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(firstCons)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(secondCons)
```

according to current orientation , BTW you can exclude centerX & heightAnchor constraints for similarity

```
myTestButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true 
myTestButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
```